# Maven Extension from private repo

Tags: maven

How is it possible to resolve a [Maven Extension](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html) configured in `.mvn/extensions.xml` from a private repository?

I have tried adding `repository` or `pluginRepository` in either `pom.xml` or `~/.m2/settings.xml`, but doesn't seem to be taken in account.